# Rails 4 validation message: removes "_id" from message

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

```
# model.rb
validates :employee_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

When left empty, the error message says "Employee can't be blank" when I want it to say "Employee ID can't be blank".

I resolved this by:

```
# model.rb
validates :employee_id, presence: { message: " ID can't be blank" }, uniqueness: true
```

which outputs "Employee ID can' be blank".

However, this isn't a really good solution IMO.  I would like some means of customizing the entire message, including the attribute prefix.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: We'd need to see how you're actually rendering the error messages to provide any kind of solution. The error message at the model level is simply `employee_id: ["can't be blank"]`. Whatever is rendering your error messages is responsible for humanizing the attribute name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several "correct" ways to go about this, but you definitely shouldn't do it via the validation itself, or by defining your own validation method.

On a model-by-model level, this is controlled by the class-level [`human_attribute_name`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Translation/human_attribute_name) method.

If you want your model's `employee_id` field to be a special case where the `_id` postfix isn't truncated, define that special case by overridding `human_attribute_name`:

```
class MyModel

  validates :employee_id, presence: true

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr, options = {})
    attr == :employee_id ? 'Employee ID' : super
  end
end
```

In broader terms, you can redefine `human_attribute_name` on `ActiveRecord::Base` to override handling of *all* `_id` attributes, but I doubt you want to do this. Generally, it's a good thing that Rails drops the `_id` postfix.

The second (and probably better) mechanism is to simply rely on localization. ActiveRecord ties into your locale YAML files for [just about everything](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models). If you want your `employee_id` field to humanize to `Employee ID` regardless of language, you'll need to edit your YAML files.

```yaml
# config/locales/en.yml

en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      employee_id: "Employee ID"
```

Comment: you're correct I don't want to remove _id for all attributes, just this one. Normally <attribute>_id is a foreign key and removing _id is beneficial.  However, in this case, employee_id is actually the "real" attribute name and not a foreign key.  It's similar to how first_name maps to "first name". For the time being I'll probably stick with the first solution, as I just need it controlled in 1 use case (model error msg next to field).

Answer (score 0):

You can override `human_attribute_name` and always send default value with id

```rb
class MyModel
  def self.human_attribute_name(attribute, options = {})
    super(attribute, { default: attribute.to_s.humanize(keep_id_suffix: true) } )
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write a custom validation. By doing it that way, you get to define the error message inside the validation method.

The relevant section from Rails Guides is here: [Performing Custom Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations)

Something like:

```
Class Paystub

  validate :employee_id_is_not_blank

  def employee_id_is_not_blank
    errors[:base] << "Employee must be a part of the record.") if id.blank?
  end
end

p = Paystub.create
p.errors.full_messages #=> ["Employee must be a part of the record."]
```

Section 7.4 in the Rails Guides specified using errors[:base]. Error messages shoveled into :base don't require an attribute to be tied to them.

**Update:** This is not the right answer. See @meagars answer above.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem. The code outputs "Employee Employee must be a part of the record." Rails automatically prefixes the error msg with the attribute name and by default Rails also humanizes attributes and removes the "_id" at the end. This may be the right direction, but won't work as-is.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Section 7.4. Use errors[:base].

Comment: @meagar I'm not doing that same thing as the OP. My solution does work, even if its at the wrong level of abstraction. Can you provide an example of how to handle this from the view layer?

Comment: @meagar What's the best way to customize the rest of the message "can't be blank". Referencing your answer above. Thank you for providing more detail and some background. (sorry to comment here, I just started contributing to SO and don't have enough rep to comment above).

Comment: @gregb Localization is still the answer. You can define `activerecord.errors.models.attributes.employee_id.blank` as "is SUPER empty!" and it will render "Employe ID is SUPER empty!". This is the preferred way of customizing all of your errors, for all of your models. There's a huge table of the supported validations here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation

Comment: thanks @meagar! I'll use localization in the future.